# How to add descending order sorting in the url in yii2 when redirecting

Tags: sorting, yii2

First of all, I am learning yii2.

I want to redirect to the particular URL with adding a "desc" "sort" (**descending order sorting**) 
I have a grid view with 4 columns in it.

I want to redirect with adding a sorting by default in the URL.

I have added the URL

```
return $this->redirect(array('city/index','UserCitySearch[citytype]' => 54));
```

**I need to add `sorting` of `"added_time"` in `descending` order in the above redirect.**

Can anyone help me how should i can add this sorting in the redirect url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what component you are using for sorting and how it's configured.

If you are using standard `yii\data\Sort` with default values the parameter that you need to set is `sort` and the descending order is done by prefixing the column name with `-`.

```php
return $this->redirect(array(
    'city/index',
    'UserCitySearch[citytype]' => 54,
    'sort' => '-added_time',
));
```

The param name depends on [`yii\data\Sort::$sortParam`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-sort#$sortParam-detail) property.

Comment: can you tell me the namespace as we add at the top of the controller with `use` for sort?

Comment: @always-a-learner sry, i don't understand what namespace you are asking for. You don't need to add any extra `use` in your controller when adding `'sort' => '-added_time'` in your redirect.

Comment: Ok can you tell me if i use `new Sort(` then like we declare that in the controller with use.

Comment: If you want to use the `Sort` class then add `use yii\data\Sort;`. But if you are using any data provider there should be no need to create new instance of `Sort` by yourself.

Comment: ok now i understand !!  thanks for the kind help I am trying to add `sort` instance in the redirect URL at a first place but now the solution you suggest is working for me. 
thanks sir